# Discrepancies in PCA results using prcomp in different R environments

Tags: r, pca

I am working on a project with a friend where we are both using the prcomp function in R to perform Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on the same dataset with the `prcomp` function. However, we have encountered an issue where the PCA results are not consistent between our two environments; specifically, the signs of some of the principal components are flipped (some values that are positive in one environment are negative in the other, and vice versa).

The R vestions are ‘4.3.1’ and '4.2.2' but I don't think this causes the issue.

Could anyone let me know why it may happen?

Comment: Not sure why it's occurring (sorry), but I remember running into this problem years ago and being told the sign doesn't matter with PCA, only the variance matters. Explained here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88882

Answer (score 1):

As @jared_mamrot said https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88882 is a very relevant answer. It is not exactly that the signs in general don't matter though, but if all the signs are flipped, it doesn't matter.

The fact that `prcomp` choses one or the other of the equivalent transformations in principal components might be linked to the order of the columns or some other random difference in the way you treat the data.